Error al actualizar SARIMAX con append: Given `endog` does not have an index that extends the index of the model
Estoy implementando modelos de predicción usando SARIMAX (sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX). Tengo guardado un modelo y quiero actualizarlo con nuevos datos. Sin embargo al correr mi código tengo siempre el mismo error, ya verifiqué mis índices y todo bien. Comparto mi código y los resultados que obtengo al correrlo:
serie_update=serie[serie['UPDATE']==1]  
serie_update[['y_log']]=np.log(serie_update[['y']]+1)
print (serie_update.set_index('ds')['y_log'])
df_exo=serie_update[['ds']].merge(df_exogenas, on='ds', how='left').fillna(0).set_index('ds')
print(modelo_old.model.data.orig_endog.index)
print(serie_update.set_index('ds').index)
print(df_exo.index)
data_mod=serie_update.set_index('ds')['y_log']
modelo_update=modelo_old.append(data_mod,  refit=False, exog=df_exo) 


Estos son los resultados que me imprime

ds
2024-11-05    0.003992
2024-11-06    0.000320
Name: y_log, dtype: float64
DatetimeIndex(['2022-04-26', '2022-04-27', '2022-04-28', '2022-04-29',
               '2022-05-02', '2022-05-03', '2022-05-04', '2022-05-05',
               '2022-05-06', '2022-05-09',
               ...
               '2024-10-22', '2024-10-23', '2024-10-24', '2024-10-25',
               '2024-10-28', '2024-10-29', '2024-10-30', '2024-10-31',
               '2024-11-01', '2024-11-04'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ds', length=655, freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2024-11-05', '2024-11-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ds', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2024-11-05', '2024-11-06'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='ds', freq=None)


El mensaje de error que me manda es:

ValueError: Given `endog` does not have an index that extends the index of the model.

Los datos originales del modelo tienen corte al 4 de noviembre, los datos que estoy actualizando son del 5 y 6 de noviembre.
Agradecería mucho me pudieran apoyar con esta situación, no logro identificar la razón exacta del error.

validastes si df_exo el indice es continuo?

@Bryro sí, justo corresponden a los dos registros que estoy actualizando, del 5 y 6 de noviembre.
